# Responsive Flexbox on small screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have 4 icons in row order on large screens, but on small screen (let's say less than 768px), I need 2 icons in row order.

Here is my current code :

```css
.welcome {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* I need the code here */
}
```

```html
<section class="container text-center">

  <h2 id="h2-welcome"><strong>Welcome to our website</strong></h2>

  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-life-ring fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Sherbimi 24/7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Shpejt & Stabil</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-globe-europe fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Kanale nga gjithe Bota</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-user-shield fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Sigurt & Shpejt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex: 0 1 50%;` in `media` and set `flex: 0 1 50%;` to `.welcome`

```css
.welcome {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .welcome div {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container text-center">

  <h2 id="h2-welcome">Welcome to our website</h2>

  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-life-ring fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Sherbimi 24/7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Shpejt & Stabil</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-globe-europe fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Kanale nga gjithe Bota</p>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <i class="fas fa-user-shield fa-5x"></i>
      <p>Sigurt & Shpejt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 2):

You can use **flex-wrap: wrap;** for force the new line items and using **flex: 0 0 50%;** for take the space of two item of a row.

```
.welcome{
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
     flex: 0 50%;
}
```

This is a CodePen:
https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/rEBKMd

Comment: You are welcome, ask me if you want some explanations.

Comment: Actually, some explanation about it would be helpful because even if I replace 0 with 50% and make it look like { flex: 50% 0; } it still works.
Also { flex: 0 1 50%; } - (someone's else reply) works as well.
So, an explanation about this would be perfect :)